# getMicrophone() in as3 only works when using setLoopBack()

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, microphone

I want to monitor the microphone audio input with flash ( as3 ).

This is just a tiny part of my code, but actually the problem is in there.

```
var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
mic.setLoopBack(true);

addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop );

function loop( event:Event ):void {
    trace( mic.activityLevel );
}
```

If i use the code like it is, i can trace the `activityLevel` and actually can see some values.. ( i think it is the volume ? )

Well, the only problem is, that the audio is also outputed to the speakers, what i DON'T want... ( `mic.setLoopBack(true);` )

But when i try `mic.setLoopBack(false);`, flash doesn't ask for microphone premissions anymore and the traced `activityLevel` stays "`-1`".....

So what can i do to disable the audio loopback OR to just monitor the audio data from the mic. ?

( when i say "audio data", i mean all the data that is necessary for later BPM detection... i think it's an byte array of the audio, isn't it ? )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `setLoopBack()`, you just need to listen for `SampleDataEvent`'s from the `Microphone`.  Note the section titled "Detecting Microphone Activity" in [this Adobe article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d1d.html), and in particular this note that talks about ways you can listen for microphone activity:

> Note: A Microphone object only dispatches Activity events when your application is monitoring the microphone. Thus, if you do not call setLoopBack( true ), add a listener for sample data events, or attach the microphone to a NetStream object, then no activity events are dispatched.

```
var mic:Microhpone = Microphone.getMicrophone;
mic.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, onSampleData);

function onSampleData(event:SampleDataEvent):void
{
    trace("activity from: " + mic.name + " level: " + mic.activityLevel);
}
```

This should be a more optimal solution, as the `SampleDataEvent`'s are only dispatched when the microphone detects sound, as opposed to your current approach that works on every frame.

Answer (score 4):

As a temp solution to mute the mic you can try :

```
var st:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);
mic.soundTransform = st;
```

You should still see the activity level.